# looking for example of DeskBand toolbar on taskbar for win7 64 bit in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, com

I am looking for a complete example for creating deskband toolbar on taskbar for win7 64bit.
 in c++.
Thanks

Comment: Recompile [the 32-bit sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716696%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as 64-bit. The interface hasn't changed. Note that [Deskbands are no longer a recommended technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511446.aspx#deskbands).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/stexbar/source/browse/#svn/trunk/StExBar)'s one example you could use.

Comment: Installing StExBar64 only creates a directory with a dll. What to do with it? I've tried registering it with regsvr32.exe but got an error that it cannot load the dll. And there's no info what to do in your project's wiki.